# Encrypt and Decrypt passwords in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, encryption, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a simple test scenario which checks the successful login into facebook, with my own credentials.I want the password to be encrypted and login with the same. How can this be done? Some code snippet would be helpful.Would decryption also be required? I am looking for somewhat the same capability like QTP has. My code snippet is as below

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKEys("encrypted password)//would want the encrypted pwd
```

Pl help

Comment: Why does it need to be encrypted?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that, over HTTPS all text are encrypted.

Comment: What I am actually looking for is that in my java code above , I don't want to use the actual password, as the script is to be used by many. What should I do?

Comment: It's not going to fix anything, your script will still need to decrypt the password and thus anybody with access to the code can do so too. It's a severe false sense of security.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be late but please try Apache's Base64 Class
please try the below code for the same

```
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));

byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Password".getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes "+ new String(encodedBytes));

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
System.out.println("decodedBytes "+ new String(decodedBytes));

pwd.sendKeys(new String(encodedBytes));
```

Hope this will work ....

Comment: All this does is encode the format and decode it. You still need some kind of private key mechanism that can turn the encrypted password to plain text. You may want to include a user prompt so a user can enter a password when they reach this page before continuing the test if you are concerned about writing an unencrypted password.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for encryption and decryption mechanism in Java similar to what qtp provides, that is not possible unfortunately. In Java you can use 'Base64' class or some other mechanism too, to encrypt and decrypt the password, but anyone having access to your code can easily figure out original value for password. As a matter of fact, by using Base64 you only avoid storing the password in it's original form. If it's a question whether anyone can pull the original password, then answer is yes, the person having access to the code can easily do that. In qtp it's different, tool itself generates the encryption which only inbuilt libraries has access to and while decryption, only tool can decrypt that. Any person can not figure out original password. Thats a very strong feature qtp provides, when it comes to automation.  I agree too. but un-fortunately it's not available in selenium.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code as well. Security of below code is little better as compared to encode and decode methods of Base64 class. Because below code requires specific key and algorithm to encode and decode. Also, below code doesn't require any additional APIs to import.

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class EncryptPassword {
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";

    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'm', 'Y', 'p', 'U', 'b', 'l', 'I', 'c', 'k', 'E', 'y', 'n', 'A',
            'e', 'E', 'M' };

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String password = "password";
        String passwordEnc = EncryptPassword.encrypt(password);
        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password + " and it's Encryption is ::    " + passwordEnc);
        String passwordDec = EncryptPassword.decrypt(passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a security expert but i think all you need to ensure is that the field is a password field using some attribute to check like type="Password" and if also when running HTTPS (Encryption)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below utility to encrypt and decrypt the test data , easy to use and effective when working with the shared data :

https://youtu.be/A6CPmKUAmT4

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)